# What kind of reporter can be used for display <img> tag?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, report

I use stimulsoft report, but this not support img tag.
I have html text and want display this on report. I searched a lot but did not get the desired result. Please introduce the appropriate reporter for this work.